# How to print out the even numbers in reverse order?

Tags: javascript, html

```
 var num = prompt("Enter an integer : ");
    var reversenum = num.reverse('');
    document.write(reversenum);
```

I want to print out the even number of integers in reverse order after inputting an integer through the prompt, but I have no idea.
Even if I try to write split(), I don't think I can separate it because the letters are attached to each other. What should I do?

```
The result I want is,
Enter an integer : 8541236954
46248
```

Comment: As `prompt` really returns a string, you can very well use `split` to make an array of the numbers. Then just reverse the array, and join back to a string. But `document.write` is not a tool which to use to show the results on the page, use proper DOM manipulation methods or properties instead.

Comment: I suppose what you mean is that, when a user provides an integer, you should generate all even numbers in reverse order, aka "all even numbers less than provided integer and more than 0`?

Comment: I didn't explain it correctly. The post has been modified.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your updated question, I suppose what you want is to extract **even-valued digits** from a given integer, and display them in reverse order.

Since `prompt()` always returns a `String`, you can do one of the two ways to split it into digits and reverse their order:

- Old-school JS way: `num.split('').reverse()`
- ES6 array spread way: `[...num].reverse()`

Then, it is just a matter of using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return even numbers. Even numbers can be selected based on the criteria that their modulus of 2 is always 0 (i.e. when number is divided by 2, it has a remainder of 0).

Finally, join your filtered array so you get a string again.

See proof-of-concept order below:

```js
const num = prompt("Enter an integer : "); // e.g. try '8541236954'
const digits = [...num].reverse();

const evenDigits = digits.filter(d => d % 2 ===0);
console.log(evenDigits.join('')); // e.g. '46248'
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You need to first split the string into an array of characters, reverse the array and then join it again. I have given an easy to understand code which converts every character of the reversed string to an *int* and checks if that integer is even, followed by concatenating it in the answer.

```js
 var num = prompt("Enter an integer : ");
 var reversenum = num.split('').reverse().join('');
 var ans = "";
 for (var i = 0; i < reversenum.length; i++)
 {
    var x = parseInt(reversenum[i]);
  if(x%2 === 0)
    ans = ans.concat(reversenum[i]);
 }
 console.log(ans);
```